# capture data from bigquery table to another bigquery table every 15 minutes

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to copy data one big query table to anther big query table which has same structure
The data should be copied every 5 minute.

How can I do that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scheduling queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

> You can schedule queries to run on a recurring basis. Scheduled
> queries must be written in standard SQL, which can include data
> definition language (DDL) and data manipulation language (DML)
> statements. You can organize query results by date and time by
> parameterizing the query string and destination table.

[image]